# Why can't I delete my accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I tried to delete my accepted answer after there was a better one out there (see [Is there any way to display numerous output neatly in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049064/is-there-any-way-to-display-numerous-output-neatly-in-matlab) ) but I discovered that it isn't possible.

What about the case where there is a better answer than the accepted one (with more upvotes etc) but the user that asked the question doesn't realize that?

Comment: sorry guys, I didn't realize this was actually asked by Jon Skeet... wow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, upvote that other answer.

Second, ask the question author in comment to his question (or your answer if he commented on it) to accept that other answer and explain why.

Third, why delete? Worst case there will be two answers, one good and one better. It's not like your answer is bad to begin with.

Comment: "why delete?" Choice?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment unlike many other places Stack Overflow is not meant to "help and forget". The content posted should have value to other people as well who come visit the question years later. Thus, if answer is good it should stay.

Comment: A non sequitur.